# Junit class - Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, junit

I am working on the Spring Framework. and made one junit class 
but i am not able to properly load the xml files needed to run the **@Test** method in junit class. In my case

- xml file are placed under folder `WEB-INF`
- the junit test class is under `test/<package_name>`

Please suggest me right way to declare the xml files in

**@ContextConfiguration**

```
@ContextConfiguration( locations={ "classpath:/applicationContext.xml",
        "classpath:/applicationDatabaseContext.xml" })
```

**Error** :

> Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener
>   [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@48fa48fa]
>   to prepare test instance [] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to
>   load ApplicationContext

Comment: are u using **maven** for your build and test?

Comment: @user1041110: please add the full exception trace. The cause of that exception is in most cases writen there, but you have truncated it.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) (recommended) then placing your Spring configuration files in the [standard location](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) `src/main/resources` (and `src/test/resources` for any test-specific configuration), then during the build these files will be copied to the `target/classes` directory.

You can reference these in your `@ContextConfiguration` with simply:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/applicationContext.xml",
                                    "/applicationContext-test.xml"})
```

If you're not using Maven, I'd still recommend using the [Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) for source and artifacts, and making your (presumably Ant-based) build process work in a similar manner.